# .htacess for HTTP_AUTHORIZATION causes server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, jwt, authorization

While developing a web application on my local machine everything worked like a charm. The problem came when I migrated the application onto the production server, which is shared hosting with basic functionalities.

I have a JWT authorization which is done through the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header. On the shared hosting, this header was missing, and doing some research about the problem led me to a solution -> paste some magic in the .htaccess file. That caused a 500 server error which I can't find a solution to.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

When I remove the second line, the header is not received. When I add it, it causes the error and I'm not entirely sure that the header is received in this case.
The third and fourth lines are needed because it's a REST API that should be routered through the index page.

What is the problem? I have limited control over the hosting.

Comment: Do you have access to the error log? That is always the first place to look, when you get a 500 and the reason is not immediately apparent.

Comment: @CBroe I've checked and the error log is empty.

Comment: When you got a 500? That is highly unlikely, unless the provider had turned off any error logging completely (which would not make much sense.) Are you sure you checked in the right location? Ask your hoster, if you are not sure. We can not look into your server from the outside, so you’re gonna need to go and get some actually useful information about the problem first.

Comment: @CBroe Your comment made me realize that I was looking into the logs from the cPanel and not the ones in the logs folder (which I forgot that I have access to...) It turned out to be a very stupid mistake with the permissions to a mongo database. Thank you for your time and help!